# Pagination past limit in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

The code listing below is in a function in a message controller. I want that a page to only have 5 records at a time on a page. Using pagination class in codeignuter i have set the limits meaning that if a page has only three records then in the pagination link in the view only one is shown e.g < 1 and not < 1 2. This also happens with the last page, if the pages are 8 it shows 9 thus <... 8 9. What am i missing

```
        $data['message_available'] = $this->getCheckForMessages();        
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "messages/inbox/";
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->getMessageCount();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config["num_links"] = 10;
        $config["full_tag_open"] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config["full_tag_close"] = '</div>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['messages'] = $this->getMessages($config['per_page'],      $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: you don't look like you are missing anything. What problem are you having?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your URL structure

Comment: @user2249879 i need your 2 queries the count query and the result query , print them here please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check  deeply this :

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->getMessageCount();
```

maybe is returning some field more than the Results query `getMessages();`

please post also your `getMessages()` and `getMessageCount();` queries to be more accurated

also please change this:

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "messages/inbox/";
```

to this:

```
$config["base_url"] = site_url('messages/inbox');
```